# how to find all overlapping substrings of length k in a sample string in python

Tags: python, string, substring

```
str1 = "ABCDEF"
```

I want to find a list of all substrings of length 3 in the above string including overlap
For example:

```
list1 = ['ABC','BCD','CDE','DEF']
```

I tried the following but it misses the overlap:

```
n = 3
lst = [str1[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(str1), n)]
```

Comment: Try using `range(0, len(str1)-n+1)`.

Comment: @Selcuk, write it as an answer so I can accept it, please

Comment: @bigbounty xrange doesn't work in Python 3. I believe its a good idea to have an updated version of the solution

Comment: @Synthase has already posted a comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x = "ABCDEF"

print ([x[i:i+3] for i in range(len(x)-2)])
```

Output:

```
['ABC', 'BCD', 'CDE', 'DEF']
```

More generally:

```
x = "ABCDEF"

n = 2

print ([x[i:i+n] for i in range(len(x)-n+1)])
```

Output:

```
['AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'DE', 'EF']
```

Even more generally:

```
x = "ABCDEF"

for n in range(len(x)+1):
    print ([x[i:i+n] for i in range(len(x)-n+1)])
```

Output:

```
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
['AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'DE', 'EF']
['ABC', 'BCD', 'CDE', 'DEF']
['ABCD', 'BCDE', 'CDEF']
['ABCDE', 'BCDEF']
['ABCDEF']
```

Comment: comprehensive and very well elucidated